# How to display Toast at center of screen

Tags: android, android-toast

In Android I want to display a toast message at the bottom of the screen, I tried this:

```
Toast.makeText(test.this, "bbb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It doesn't work, how do I do it correctly?

Comment: It didn't make any sense to me. What are you exactly trying to say?

Comment: format text, correct question, sample code what did you try, did you even try use search engine ?

Comment: People who edit this question edit it wrong... The question is clear, the message body is not... please edit it again. What he want to ask is "How to display Toast message at center of the screen" , the message is "In android I want to display a Toast message at the center of the screen, to display a toast message at the bottom of the screen I try this 
Toast.makeText(test.this,"bbb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
How do I place a Toast message at the middle of the screen?"
I think was something like that, not as it was edited...

Answer (score 297, accepted):

**Not Applicable after Android 11:**

To display the **Toast** in center of the screen.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(test.this, "bbb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: If someone wants to adjust the position further, the third argument in setGravity takes in the yAxis offset in pixels.

Comment: `setGravity()` should have returned Toast to be able to chain it.  Oh well, missed opportunity!

Comment: Warning: Starting from Android R, for apps targeting API level R or higher, this method is a no-op when called on text toasts.

Answer (score 7):

Before Android 11, to center a **Toast**, use:

Kotlin:

```
val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
toast.show()
```

Java:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Or a custom view.

**Warning**: starting on Android 11 (R, API 30), you have no non-legacy way to display a centered toast on Android 11 and above:

- the gravity is **not** working anymore. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int).
- the custom view is **not** working, when called from the background (and deprecated anyway). See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setView(android.view.View)

Comment: Is there some way to achieve/mimic this in Android 11?

Comment: You can mimic this by using the DecorView (the top view of your hierarchy, so you can add a custom view here that will be display above all the others). However it will not work cross-Activity (e.g. if you trigger the "toast" on one Activity and finish it right away, with a toast it will remain visible on the other activity, with the decor view it won't)

Answer (score 4):

I have tried almost all the ways to make my Toast in center of screen, but it didn't worked for me anyhow (**I am having Android 11 Device**). So, I and [Ruturaj Rathod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15266785/rathod-ruturaj-sinh) found a solution to make a Custom Toast.

Warning: **I don't know whether this way is a good practice or not.**

Let's see how its made in Android Studio, though its Custom Toast its totally modifiable.

Make a new Layout file for example: toast_layout.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#2d2d2d"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the custom toast"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your .java file (wherever you want to show your Custom Toast):

```
View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));
    Toast toast = new Toast(MainActivity.this);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(v);
    toast.show();
```

And, your Custom Toast will look like:

[Custom Toast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELoAA.png)

Comment: setting cardBackgroundColor="#efefef" , cardCornerRadius="20dp",  and textColor="#424242"  creates the same effect as the real toast message

Comment: Now setView() is deprecated. Perhaps Google Android want to say that they will not let you create custom toast at any cost!

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin.Android, this displays toast at center of screen:

```
            Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "bbb", ToastLength.Long);
            toast.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center, 0, 0);
            toast.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Layout file for custom toast

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textColor="#000" />
```

.java file for custom toast on button's click event

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToast);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // get your custom_toast.xml ayout
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
              (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

            // set a dummy image
            ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            // set a message
            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Button is clicked!");

            // Toast...
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Showing/ Setting text gravity at center (Horizontally) in koltin

```
fun Context.longToast(msg: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .apply {
           view.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.message)?.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        }
        .show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used to display Toast message

```
Toast tt = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your text displayed here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
tt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
tt.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin;

```
val toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Yes clicked...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0)
            toast.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(test.this, "bbb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).apply{
setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)}.show()
```

This way you can do it in one line.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this line:

```
  setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)}.show()
```

this can not work on Android 11

Answer (score -2):

The below code worked for me.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast in center", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0).show();
```

Comment: setGravity does not return Toast object. void setGravity (int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset)